# Redux reducer error when firing unrelated action

Tags: reactjs, redux

I get strange error, when firing unrelated action.

[image]

articlesReducer.js

```

```
import merge from "lodash/merge";

const articles = (state = {}, action) => {
  if (action.payload && action.payload.entities && action.payload.entities.articles) {
    return merge({}, state, action.payload.entities.articles);
  }
  return state;
};

export default articles;
```

```

Action that causes error:

```

```
export const changeHomePageTabTo = tab => ({
  type: actionTypes.HOMEPAGE_CHANGE_TAB,
  payload: { tab }
});
```

```

If I change it to:

`export const changeHomePageTabTo = tab => ({
  type: actionTypes.HOMEPAGE_CHANGE_TAB,
  tab
});`

Everything works fine. Can't figure it out what causes this. Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: You should be looking at the type from the action, not the payload itself. You'll get many errors like that because something does not exists on the payload. Oh and btw lodash/merge mutates the object, that's not recommended, never mutate the state directly.

Comment: That's taken directly from redux docs, using merge with those parameters does not mutate state.

Comment: as per merge(), the first parameter is the merge target, which in the example is just a blank object.

Comment: could it be because you have the payload key? action.payload

Comment: Yes, I figured that out, but why it's clashing ? I'm checking if payload is entities, if not return state;